# Appscript insertar imágenes en servicio HtmlService.createHtmlOutput

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, script

Buen día tengo el siguiente cuestionamiento:
Usando AppScript cargo la informacion de un googlesheet los parametros y creo el appscript web:

```
function doGet(e) {
  registrarAsistencia(e.parameter.dni,e.parameter.nombre,e.parameter.imagen);

 return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`
  Asistencia registrada correctamente <br><br>
  Documento: ${e.parameter.dni} <br>
  Nombres y Apellidos: ${e.parameter.nombre} <br>
  Fecha y Hora: ${new Date()}<br>
  <img src= ${e.parameter.imagen}>`);
}
```

Pero al Implementarlo lo concateno con los parametros y me el indica error siguiente:

```
> Exception: Contenido HTML con formato incorrecto: Asistencia
> registrada correctamente <br><br> Documento: 43466208 <br> Nombres y
> Apellidos: Arturo Flores <br> Fecha y Hora: Tue Nov 29 2022 15:40:27
> GMT-0500 (hora estándar de Perú)<br> <img src=
> http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view> (línea 4, archivo "Código")
```

O es por que el parametro de imagen esta mal planteado:

```
"?dni="&a2&"&nombre="&b2&"&imagen=http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1he8VXfcqNyzBp911ZEBezG2-..."
```

Gracias

Comment: Falta contexto en tu pregunta. ¿Qué hay en `registrarAsistencia()`? ¿Qué hay en `e.parameter`? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: Si en asistencia se carga desde una google sheet la cual es una tabla de dni -  nombres- imagen (ruta de la imagen en preview desde Drive).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9sDT41h7Fts&t=378s  se basa en este video, solo se esta agregando un campo mas de imagen y quiero q la imagen que se coloca en la tabla se pueda visualizar al momento de leer el QR y cargue la informacion en la web que se genera en el Appscript +51997618806

Comment: El código relativo a la pregunta debe estar en la pregunta, no en fuentes externas como Youtube. Te sugiero que intentes meter el contenido que pasas a `createHtmlOutput()` en una variable y que hagas debug de esa variable. Algo así más o menos: `var outPut=Asistencia registrada correctamente <br><br>
  Documento: ${e.parameter.dni} <br> ...etc ;` Y para hacer debug pones: `Logger.log(outPut);` y revisas que el contenido que se crea es  HTML válido.